# slf4j fails to bind logger, despite logback existing on classpath

Tags: java, maven, neo4j, logback, slf4j

When running integration tests for a project, the following error is logged:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
```

According to documentation, this error can only occur when a logger implementation is not on the classpath, however, the following Maven dependencies exist:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>${logback}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>${logback}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Furthermore, when Neo4j 2.x is on the classpath, the problem *does not occur*, however with Neo4j 3.x *it does*.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. You can try to find all Logback dependencies on your classpath and remove/shade all of them, which are duplicated.

And look at this link, maybe it will help: http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder

[Maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Try this:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.slf4j:slf4j-api
# you can add "-DoutputType=dot | grep -E "log|slf4j" to get a better idea
```

to do a deep search among all transitive dependencies(dep of deps). You may find some of your dependencies are using slf4j.

If that is the case, add slf4j in your project pom as direct dep, so you can shade the one used in your dep. And add logback/log4j dep in your project, too.

I use this:

```xml
        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Where `${slf4j.version}` is `1.7.9`, current stable one(with no alpha/beta postfix).